# How to prevent EasyPHP DevServer 16 to add prefix 'edsa' for alias

Tags: wordpress, apache, alias, easyphp

I'm coming from EasyPHP DevServer 14, with a lot of websites developed for many customers, and I used to have a custom alias 'workspace', but now, in EasyPHP 16, they made obligatory the use of a prefix 'edsa' in every defined alias, breaking my WordPress installations. How could I solve that?

Comment: Also interested in this. It baffles me why anyone would introduce something as stupid as this and make it mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be hardcoded in a code (...), but fortunately the code is in php, so you can just edit it out and be OK (until the update I guess).
Go to the eds-dashboard subdirectory and edit the index.php file.

In the current version (17), the code is on the line 95:

```
$new_alias[0]['alias_name'] = 'edsa-' . $_POST['alias_name'];
```

Just remove the silly part from it

```
$new_alias[0]['alias_name'] = $_POST['alias_name'];
```

save the file and you should be done.

Tested on windows

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this solution which works like a charm!

One should also alter the line 511 in order to print the name of the alias properly in the dashboard. Otherwise, by default, the PHP script removes the 5 first characters, which are supposed to be "edsa-".

Change :

```
<?php echo wordwrap(substr($alias['alias_name'],5), 20, "<br />", true); ?>
```

for:

```
<?php echo wordwrap(substr($alias['alias_name'],0), 20, "<br />", true); ?>
```

Tested on Dev Server 17 for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would also replace the html part of the page, changing:

```
<p style="color:silver;padding-left:25px;"><b>Note</b>: the prefix 'edsa-' will be added to the name in order to avoid any conflict.</p>
```

to:

```
<!--p style="color:silver;padding-left:25px;"><b>Note</b>: the prefix 'edsa-' will be added to the name in order to avoid any conflict.</p-->
```

And two lines after that:

```
<span class="input-group-addon input-sm">edsa-</span>
```

to:

```
<span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><!-- edsa- --></span>
```